# Return rows with set time difference in elements within cell (containing datetime64ns) Python dataframe np.array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to find a way to just return rows of a dataframe that have a difference of 24 hours or less between the first and second element within a particular cell.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemID': [23146, 23146, 23146, 23191, 23198, 23198],
                    'CustomerID': ['23166', '23167', '23168', '23169', '23170', '23171'],
                   'Value': [11, 21, 22, 53, 15, 8],
                    'TransDts': [(['2011-01-26T14:30:00.000000000', '2011-04-07T10:43:00.000000000']), 
                          (['2011-01-26T14:30:00.000000000', '2011-01-26T14:45:00.000000000']), 
                          (['2011-01-26T14:45:00.000000000', '2011-01-26T14:55:00.000000000']), 
                          (['2011-01-26T14:30:00.000000000', '2011-01-27T10:43:00.000000000']), 
                          (['2011-01-26T14:30:00.000000000', '2011-01-28T10:43:00.000000000']), 
                          (['2011-01-26T14:30:00.000000000', '2011-01-29T10:43:00.000000000'])]})
```

The df contains transnational data and the 'TransDts' columns always contains 2 datetimes - and I only want to return (or flag) rows in which the transactions are within 24 hours of eachother.

Any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to realize something non-obvious: the Pandas `.str` accessor will let you index not only into strings but also into lists stored as elements.  You can subtract the pairs of times like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.TransDts.str[1]) - pd.to_datetime(df.TransDts.str[0])
```

The result is:

```
0   70 days 20:13:00
1    0 days 00:15:00
2    0 days 00:10:00
3    0 days 20:13:00
4    1 days 20:13:00
5    2 days 20:13:00
Name: TransDts, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

So just check if that's less than `pd.to_timedelta('1d')`, perhaps with `.abs()` first if you want to check for 1 day in either direction:

```
diff = pd.to_datetime(df.TransDts.str[1]) - pd.to_datetime(df.TransDts.str[0])
df[diff.abs() < pd.to_timedelta('1d')]
```

That gives you rows 1, 2 and 3.